# better options for writing this jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a html file like the following one,

```
<i class=‘icon-calendar icon-large' data-placement='top' data-toggle='popover' type='button'>
  <div class='head hide'>Calendar</div>
    <div class='content hide'>
      <form action="#" data-remote="true" id="calendar_form" method="post">
        <div style="...">
          <input type="hidden" />
          <input type="hidden" />
        </div> 
            <table border='0px'>
             <tbody>
               <tr>
                <td colspan='2'>
                  <button class='btn btn-default btn-block' id='submit' type='submit'>Convert</button>
                </td>
             </tbody>
            </table>
         </form>
        </div>
       </i>

<li class="..." id="calendar_example"><label class=" label" for="...">...</label>
  <input class="..." id="calendar_example_1" name="[calendar_example][0][calendar_example_1][0]" type="text" />
```

I'm trying to use Jquery to write the function as when click button where id is submit, i can pass value from the popover to the field with id calendar_example_1, my code, the working one to find the field, is

```
 $(function(){
   $('body').on('click','#submit', function(){
    var calendar_name = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().siblings().find('#calendar_example_1').attr('name');
    return false;
  });
 });
```

by using .parent() multiple times, i don't think this is a good way to write this code. As i'm new to jquery, i can't find any better solution yet that works the way i want. Anyone can give me some suggestion?

EDIT:
 the outside form is nested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just do this instead:

```
var calendar_name = $(this).closest("i.icon-calendar").siblings("li#calendar_example").find('#calendar_example_1').attr('name');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
var calendar_name = $('#calendar_example_1').attr('name');
});
```

Comment: Oddly, we've tried using the similar way as yours, it didn't work at all. With just $('#submit').click(function(){, the popover couldn't show up.